# Manually Creating rolling window in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I want to create a function of rolling window that moves through time (example window_size=2 sec) and gives me mean of column 'temp'.

Here is the dataset:

```py
data = { 
  'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
  'temp': [20, 26, 28, 30, 31, 33, 29, 34, 16, 35, 38, 31]
}
```

The dataset I want

```py
data = {
  'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
  'temp': [20, 26, 28, 30, 31, 33, 29, 34, 16, 35, 38, 31],
  'mean': [23, 27, .....]
```

I tried the `DataFrame.rolling` method, but I can only get the mean based on a fixed window size. I need the mean of the column with a flexible window size defined by another column.

Comment: Your question wasn't very clear for a number of reason (conflicting sentence, lack of punctuation, etc.). I took a stab at cleaning it up. Let me know if changed its spirit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_in['mean'] = df_in['temp'].rolling(2).mean().shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
    time  temp  mean
0      1    20  23.0
1      2    26  27.0
2      3    28  29.0
3      4    30  30.5
4      5    31  32.0
5      6    33  31.0
6      7    29  31.5
7      8    34  25.0
8      9    16  25.5
9     10    35  36.5
10    11    38  34.5
11    12    31   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. It works ,But please,can you just explain what that shift(-1) is for.

Comment: @user2330646 The shift is to move the series back one step. Remove the shift and you will see that the first value is NAN because it is try to average the value before time 1 which doesn't exists.